# Java ME - seeking tutorials

Tags: java, java-me

I'm pretty new at Java, but have got some experience with Java SE lately.

Now I wanna begin making applications for mobile, but I can't seem to find any good tutorials of Java ME that is not from 2005 or earlier...

Someone knows about any good beginners tutorials?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i am sending you some good links.

[first and most important link:](http://www.j2mesalsa.com/j2meindex.html)

[second one is:](http://www.roseindia.net/j2me/)

hope it'll help you..

good luck

Answer (score 1):

welcome to the club... J2ME is practically dead so the resources are limited

- first of all http://archive.org/web/ will be your best friend to find old pages that are no longer availible ;)
- nokia has loads of resourses [http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Category:Java_ME](http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Category%3aJava_ME)
- and for GUI there is a really good library called LWUIT 
  https://lwuit.java.net/
  and its blog http://lwuit.blogspot.co.il/